# Custom taxonomy and post type rewrite rules

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm working on portfolio site, where I need to create a "portfolio" post type and divide posts in it by categories with urls like "/portfolio/category/", so the "category" is the category term.

/portfolio/ - custom post type "portfolio"

/portfolio/category/ - custom taxonomy "portfolio_category", related to "portfolio" type.

/portfolio/post/ - post of the "portfolio" custom post type.

What is the best way to make this url structure?

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand you :)

I think the easiet way (in my humble opion) the best way is to use taxomonies like so:

```
function portfolio_taxomony() {
register_taxonomy( 'portfolio', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Web Design', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );  
}

add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_taxomony', 0 );
```

*(Web Design if of course an example)*

That way you'll have a url like this:
**http://www.site.com/portfolio/web-design/postname/**

To me that looks great from an seo point of view because the url is like a "story" and also, easy to do..